# To upload the image file to a web form

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I do have some image files(.png files) in document directory(iPhone). I am viewing web forms(.aspx) on the UIWebView. when I click on the submit button of the form, i just want to attach the image file to the form and wants to send that file to the web server along with the web form.

The thing I m suffering from is, i am not getting how to attach an image file to the web form and how to submit those two.

Kindly help me out of this. I am not getting any of the hint how to do it.

Thanking you....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to modify these examples to work for you, but they are working examples.

### Objective-C

**`MyViewController.m:`**

```
- (void) upload
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yourwebsite.com/uploads/upload.php";
    NSData *data = /* turn your png into NSData */

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /* now lets create the body of the post */
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n",@"yourPng"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:content] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];  
}
```

### PHP

**`upload.php:`**

```
<?php
//assuming upload.php and upload folder are in the same dir
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
$product = $_GET[product];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
    echo "PNG uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
    echo "PNG not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000)     //Limiting image at 300K
{
    exit("Your file is too large."); 
}

// Add support here for PNG files:
if ((!($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "text/plain")) &&  //Also allowing 
    (!($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "text/plist")) &&  //plist files
    (!($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "text/html")))     //HTML files
{
    exit("Incorrect file type.  " . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] . " is the file type you uploaded."); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');    //Not necessary, I was using these
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');    //going wrong.
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "http://www.yourwebsite.com/uploads/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sir, your code is helping me out. But, the thing is, will u pls post the sever side code in C#.Net that you have already posted in php. I am looking for the C#.net language for getting the NSData at the server side....

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to upload file from iphone safari.
you are screwed, there is no support to upload file from iPhone safari.

`<input type="FILE"/>` will be disable.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem! Last echo line is what needed to be adjusted!

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file  ./
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 3000000000000000) {
exit("Your file is too large."); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
$postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
$canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
$tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
$maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
echo "http://localhost:8888/wouldYa/images/{$randomNumber}{$file}" . "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Now I am in the mist of saving the Str in Xcode, to another PHP file to insert the filename to  that user's section in my table, specifically the display picture section, this  should be no hard and implemented :-)

If you are interested in my full source code, please let me know, I know it is not that secure yet but soon it will.

Comment: Is there any restriction on file size?