# How to upload photos to my server with an iOS hybrid web/binary Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm working on a hybrid app for iOS,

This application is a binary which basically contains a `UIWebView` to use my client's web service. The binary does also provide feedback to the user about the connectivity status of the device (using reachability).

There's a feature that I'm working on now, which basically requires a user to fill a small web form in the UIWebView, and that should allow the user to "attach" a picture (e.g avatar).

I was wondering if I could exploit the fact that I'm wrapping the `UIWebView` (to interact with the web service) in a binary to handle the image upload for the user without having to leave my Application?

I'm open to possible solutions.

Cheers.

Comment: It seems similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151004/to-upload-the-image-file-to-a-web-form  From the answers, it may not be possible.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `UIImagePickerController`. It allows the user to pick images from the Photos app or the Camera within your application. Then you can upload the selected image to your server using `NSURLConnection`. The presence of `UIWebView` is irrelevant.

Comment: The presence of UIWebView is relevant because that is how the app interacts with the web service.